# How to display the formated date with two characters timezone (Ex: ET instead of EST)

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

Able to change the format of the date using SimpleDateFormat. But unable to chnage the timezone format to two characters just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056778/php-datetime-show-time-in-et-instead-of-est-or-edt)

Want the same logic for Java/Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't, because Standard vs Daylight matters.

If you absolutely must, do a regular expression replace after formatting:

```
dateFormat.format(date).replaceFirst("([ECMP])[SD]T", "$1T")
```